# How to change a port on a server into a different IP address in centos 7

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, centos7, httpd.conf

I've got a few web servers running on my local network and, I wanted to change a specific port on a web server into IP address so that I can easily proxy them over nginx and also have access to them locally via Bind. I've got a server [HTTPD] with a few WordPress sites running on different ports [i.e 80, 8080 ETC] and I would like to change those into a private IP address locally. This is a complicated problem of the fact that  I cannot specify port numbers on my local DNS, and I also don't want to install another nginx server on the local sites. Thanks guys

Comment: When you say local IP, where is this machine? On a home network or a cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Search the web for "Centos 7 IP Aliasing" and set up a new IP address that connects to your machine. Then configure a new virtual host to listen on that new IP address.

I would give you more info, except A) IP aliasing on Centos 7 is more involved than I like (much easier on Solaris), and B) I'm not familiar at all with configuring Nginx (very easy on Apache).

@Tarun Lalwani asks a good question regarding whether this is a home or local network vs. a public one. You have to pay $$ for a public IP address as they are a scarce, managed resource, whereas your local network can accommodate almost as many IP's as you can think of. Anyone on your local network can access your service on your machine using those extra IP's. However, accessing those local IP's from the Public Internet is a separate topic altogether, involving router configurations and NAT addressing.

It may not be the precise answer you're looking for, but at least it should give you a direction to continue looking.